# Text to dynamic Xpath

Tags: infopath, default-value, xpath

Is it possible to use dynamic text to XPath in InfoPath?

Example:

Use a field with text:

```
"xdXDocument:GetDOM("Org")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Manager/pc:Person/pc:AccountId"
```

then will be set as Value in another field and it gets the result of the field in the data connection (the Manager in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, put the answer here if someone else might need it:

I have used another Data connection to get the type:

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("ValueSource")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Value
```

contains the value "d:Manager"

then integrate in the XPath expression:

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("Org")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/*[name() = string(xdXDocument:GetDOM("ValueSource")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW/d:Value)]/pc:Person/pc:DisplayName
```